# How do I change the browsers location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, navigation, window

I'm writing a legal consent page which works in a similar way to a sign in page, in that it is totally separate from the main website.  The main website sends users to the page with a query parameter of where it would like them to return to.

The main site has a url like this:

```
portal.myCloudProject.company.cloud
```

The URL I'm accessing the consent page looks like this:

```
consent.differentCloudProject.company.cloud?origURL="portal.myCloudProject.company.cloud"
```

When the user consents by clicking a button, I want the browser to navigate to origURL.  My code looks like this:

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var returnURL = searchParams.get('origURL') as string;
console.log(returnURL);
window.location.replace(returnURL);
```

However when I click the consent button, my browser navigates to:

```
consent.differentCloudProject.company.cloud/portal.myCloudProject.company.cloud
```

I've also tried to set the location like this:

```
window.location.assign(returnURL);
```

and

```
window.location.href = returnURL;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you set the protocol it should work, like so: `window.location.href = 'https://yourdomain.com';`.

Comment: `window.location.href  = window.location.protocol + "//"  + returnURL; ` you need to add protocol otherwise it'll just add `returnURL` to current domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location.replace("//" + returnURL);`